# Modeling an Increasing Process

Tags: time-series, bayesian

I want to model an unobserved, increasing (non-stationary) AR(1) process in a Bayesian setting

$$X_t= 1.2 X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

How does one model the residuals, $\epsilon_t$ to ensure that $X_t < X_{t+1}$ always? One possibility is to consider $\epsilon_t \sim \text{Exp}\left(\lambda\right)$. Also what prior does one setup on $X_0$ ? The process is not stationary so one cannot just use the long-run mean or variance as typically done in a Gaussian setup.

Is there a better way to model increasing processes ? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to force $X_t > X_{t-1}$?

Comment: If this is an AR process then $\epsilon_t$ must be independent from $X_{t-1}$ and hence must have a distribution that excludes negative values.

Comment: @jbowman. That is the requirement. I want it to increase. Say $X_t = t^2$

Comment: @X'ian. You are correct. That is the reason I put an exponential distribution, because it is easy. Gamma, Cauchy, lognormal have a non-exponential/polynomial term which will get the mean and make a mess when computing the likelihood. I want something tractable

Comment: The Cauchy does not have a mean and is not confined to positive values, so I'm not sure why you have it on your list.  The likelihoods of the Gamma and lognormal distributions are in fact easy to work with.   With modern computers, evaluating something of the form $x^{r-1}$ (or  $r\log x$) really isn't a problem.  You should pick a distribution that fits the process, not use something rather extreme like the Exponential distribution just because it has, say, one parameter instead of two!

Comment: @Jbowman. My apologies. I meant to write Chi-square. Was not careful in checking but now I can't edit the comment. Also, as said in the question, the process is latent, so fitting is out of question.